# java created zip file with directory inside cannot unzip by winrar

Tags: java, zip, unzip, winrar

I have created a zip file using java zip utility and I have following directory structure inside that zip file.

> 1. test.txt - file
> 2. mylabel.lbl - file
> 3. aux - directory (inside this directory I have some other files like following)
>
>    > 1. myfile.lbl
>    > 2. firstfile.txt

```
String dir = "aux\\";
        Iterator<LabelFile> i = auxLabelFiles.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            LabelFile labelFile = i.next();
            String lableFileName = labelFile.getMetadata().getLabelFileName();
            zipEncorder.addToZip(dir + lableFileName, labelFile.getMedia().getByteData());
        }
```

This is code only 'aux' directory and once the file is downloaded in can be opened with 7zip and shows directory structure correctly.

When I try to unzip zip file with WinRAR it unzips all only outer directory files with an error message. '**cannot create aux\myfile.lbl system cannot find the path specified**'

I cannot guess is this an issue with the file was created or WinRAR issue.

Any comment is appreciated.

Thanks,
Dil.

Comment: Isn't `aux` a reserved reference under windows, like `null`?

Comment: Thats right.. It resolved my issue. I just changed the name to 'Auxiliary' and working fine now. Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is directory `aux` in the ZIP archive as **AUX** is a reserved name which cannot be used as name for a file or directory on Windows, see MSDN article [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx). Therefore renaming the directory to something different like `Auxiliary` solves the problem.